# Find only parents where join-condition matches

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two Models related. Now I need to retrieve data from the Field-Model where the joined condition on the UserField matches:

I have the ID of the UserField and want to get its related Field(-data):
The corresponding sql would look like this:

```
SELECT Field.* 
FROM fields AS Field 
  JOIN user_fields AS UserField 
    ON UserField.field_id = Field.id 
WHERE UserField.id = 3;
```

I want to write this with cake-model logic.

### Models:

```
class Field extends AppModel {
     public $hasMany = array(
          'UserField' => array(
               'className' => 'UserField',
               'foreignKey' => 'field_id'
          )
     );
}

class UserField extends AppModel {
     public $belongsTo = array(
          'Field' => array(
               'className' => 'Field'
          )
     );
}
```

### Find:

```
$this->Field->hasMany['UserField']['conditions'] = array('UserField.id' => 3);
$this->Field->find('all');
```

**Result** of the query are all Fields while UserField is only set where the condition is matching. I need to restrict the results to only that matching case:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Field' => array(
            'id' => (int) 1
        ),
        'UserField' => array()
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Field' => array(
            'id' => (int) 2
        ),
        'UserField' => array()
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Field' => array(
            'id' => (int) 3
        ),
        'UserField' => array(
            'id' => (int) 3
        )
    )
)
```

### What I expect

```
array(
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Field' => array(
            'id' => (int) 3
        ),
        'UserField' => array(
            'id' => (int) 3
        )
    )
)
```

The UserField is optional, I only want to retrieve the Field data.

Comment: In your second Model declaration did you mean `class User` ???

Comment: my bad, copy-paste-error, i've corrected the models.

Comment: Okay, try my answer. I assumed that was the case.

Comment: Can you paste your SQL schema? perhaps the fields aren't named properly for Cake's magic to occur?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something likes this I believe:

```
$rows = $this->Field->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'UserField.id' => 3
    )
);
```

Comment: This was my first approach, too. Problem is that cake does not join the models, and therefore throws an error Unknown column "UserField.id" in where clause.
Cake's resulting sql looks like this: SELECT `Field`.`id` FROM `fields` AS `Field` WHERE `UserField`.`id` = 3

Comment: If cake is not joining the models then you have an issue with your declarations. I don't see any issues right off the bat but if you try to bake, they might fix it for you. You shouldn't have to add any special join code

Comment: If I drop the condition, I can see that I get both, Fields and UserFields. So cake does join the models.
I simply can't add a condition for the 'other' model.

Comment: Here's the relevant part of the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html " Let’s say you had a belongsTo relationship between Posts and Authors. Let’s say you wanted to find all the posts that contained a certain keyword (“magic”) or were created in the past two weeks, but you wanted to restrict your search to posts written by Bob"

Comment: Seems to work if I explicitly take the way over the UserField writing $this->Field->UserField->find(...).

Comment: although I don't really understand why this is neccessary since the $hasMany attribute alredy defines the connected models.